# Oracle DB: Scheduled job failing with error: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

Tags: oracle, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create a scheduled job in Oracle DB, from which, I need to execute a stored procedure.

I have created the procedure like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "delete_old_transactions" AS
BEGIN
  DELETE from EVENT_JOURNAL where EVENT_JOURNAL.WRITE_TIMESTAMP < (((SYSDATE-CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01-01-1970 00:00:00+00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') as date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  DELETE from SNAPSHOT where SNAPSHOT.CREATED < (((SYSDATE-CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01-01-1970 00:00:00+00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') as date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) - (4 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
END;
```

The stored procedure compiles fine and gets created successfully.

I created the scheduled job like:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name           =>  'delete_old_transactions_job',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   start_date         =>  SYSTIMESTAMP,
   enabled            =>  true,
   job_action         =>  'delete_old_transactions',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=2;',
   job_class          =>  'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
   comments           =>  'Job for deleting old transactions.');
END;
```

The scheduled job also gets created and is executing after every 2 minutes as desired, but it is failing in the execution and returns an error:

> ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "delete_old_transactions" 
                            -                       -
                            this                    this
```

Why did you use double quotes? **Remove them**. In Oracle, everything is stored into data dictionary in uppercase, but you can reference them any way you want (upper/lower/mixed case).

But, if you use double quotes while creating objects, you have to use the same double quotes and match letter case **exactly** every time you reference those objects.

Therefore, the simplest option is to recreate the procedure, but this time remove double quotes.

Or, put double quotes into `DBMS_SCHEDULER`:

```
job_action         =>  '"delete_old_transactions"',
```

but that's not particularly good idea.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the procedure to upper case and it works fine now.

Comment: You shouldn't have done that. It would be enough to `create or replace procedure delete_old_transactions`. That's all. No uppercase, no double quotes.

Comment: don't forget to drop procedure "delete_old_transactions";

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help in understanding how oracle treats case-sensitivity of object names.  Here I am playing with table names, just for the sake of a simpler demo. But the same applies to all object names - tablespaces, tables, columns, functions, procedures, packages, etc.

Pay close attention to the treatment of the table name:

```
SQL> conn scott/tiger@pdb01
Connected.
SQL> --
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> -- Create mixed-case table
SQL> create table "MyDemo"
  2     (col1 varchar2(20))
  3  ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into "MyDemo" values ('mixed case');

1 row created.

SQL> -- create default case table
SQL> create table MyDemo
  2     (col1 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into MyDemo values ('default');

1 row created.

SQL> --
SQL> select table_name
  2  from user_tables
  3  where upper(table_name)='MYDEMO';

TABLE_NAME
--------------------
MyDemo
MYDEMO

2 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select * from mydemo;

COL1
--------------------
default

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from MyDemo;

COL1
--------------------
default

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from "MyDemo";

COL1
--------------------
mixed case

1 row selected.

SQL> -- clean up
SQL> drop table mydemo;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table "MyDemo";

Table dropped.

SQL> --
SQL> spo off
SQL> edit demo.log
SQL> insert into MyDemo values ('default');

1 row created.

SQL> --
SQL> select table_name
  2  from user_tables
  3  where upper(table_name)='MYDEMO';

TABLE_NAME
--------------------
MyDemo
MYDEMO

2 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select * from mydemo;

COL1
--------------------
default

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from MyDemo;

COL1
--------------------
default

1 row selected.

SQL> select * from "MyDemo";

COL1
--------------------
mixed case

1 row selected.

SQL> -- clean up
SQL> drop table mydemo;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table "MyDemo";

Table dropped.
```